# Php Array removing duplication and string conversion

Tags: php

hi i have output of an array as follow:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 66, 65, 64 
[1] => 57 
[2] => 66,23 
[3] => 66
)
```

How can i remove duplication values and convert the collection into comma separated string? The unique output is `66,65,64,57,23`. Thanks

Comment: i only tried convert an array into comma separated string

Comment: What is name of your array variable. add whole code so everyone can understand easily.

Comment: Assuming those are all strings, `explode` each string on `,`, `trim` each resulting individual number, put them all in one array, `array_unique` it, `join` it.

Comment: Is '66, 65, 64' a string or is it an array like [0] => array(66, 65, 64) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `array_unique()` and `array_reverse()`:

```
$array = Array ( 
  0 => '66, 65, 64',
  1 => '57', 
  2 => '66,23',
  3 => '66',
);
$collection = array();
foreach($array as $numbers) {
  $nums = explode(',', $numbers);
  foreach($nums as $num) {
    $collection[] = trim($num);
  }
}
// unique and sort
$collection = array_unique($collection, SORT_NUMERIC);
// reverse it so that it can be descending order
$collection = array_reverse($collection);
print_r($collection);
```

which will output :

```
Array (
  [0] => 66
  [1] => 65
  [2] => 64
  [3] => 57
  [4] => 23
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you iterate through the array and add it to a final array by checking its values then `implode` to construct a string.

```
$array = Array ( 
0 => array(66, 65, 64), 
1 => array(57), 
2 => array(66,23), 
3 => array( 66)
); 

$final = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
   foreach ($item as $num) {
       if (!in_array($num, $final)) $final[] = $num;
   }
}

$str = implode(",", $final);
echo $str
```

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to trim the space.

Answer (score 0):

well, the code is lil ugly...

```
$test = [
 '0' => '66, 65',
 '1' => '80', '66'
];
$temp = implode(',', array_map('trim', array_unique(explode(',', implode(',', $test)))));
print_r($test);
print_r($temp);
```

//output

```
 Array (
  [0] => 66, 65
  [1] => 80
  [2] => 66 
  ) 

 66,65,80
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok:

```
<?php

$array = array( 
     "66, 65, 64", 
     57, 
     "66,23", 
     66
);

function dosplit($a,$b) {
    if (preg_match("/,/",$b)) {
        $a = array_merge($a, preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $b));
    } else {
        array_push($a, $b);
    }
    return $a;
}
$result = array_reduce($array, 'dosplit' ,array());
$array = array_unique($result);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(   
    [0] => 66
    [1] => 65
    [2] => 64
    [3] => 57
    [5] => 23
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might is useful for you:

```
$array = array(
    "66, 65, 64 ",
    "57",
    "66,23",
    "66",
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
//to make single line
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $singleline.=$val . ",";
}
echo $singleline . "</br>";
//remove the "," end of the value
$endvlaue = rtrim($singleline, ",");
echo $endvlaue;
//make an array
$val = explode(",", $endvlaue);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($val);
echo "<pre>";
//make uniqu
$finalvalue = array_unique($val);
echo "<pre>";
//make , seperator
print_r(implode(",", $finalvalue));
```